# Restarting Python to show changes

Tags: python, django

I am new to the python script. How do you restart a python script with Django through SSH?

Comment: That will kill any `python` process.

Comment: With respect, By the sounds of it you shouldn't be any where near the production server, it would be better to have a deployment script the dev can use to make changes

Comment: It's probably best if you talk to your developer about what you want (changing a logo, it seems). She'll tell you whether it's something she has to do, or how you can safely do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running pkill python in the ssh works.

Comment: I believe this is really bad practice because `pkill python` will kill all programs which is running with python. Any scripts, workers and all python processes will be killed and will not restarted automatically. It's better to use `ps -ef | grep python` to get PIDs of python processes and kill one you need with `kill -9 PID_of_process`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you project is django based.
Django framework has a project directory, where static files are initially placed. And when you run your project for development purposes, django takes all static from the project static directory.

But for the production django deployment usually get runned command `manage.py collectstatic` to `copy` all static into another place. And sometimes there are another command - compress. To compress that static.

This is done to make webserver (apache or ngingx) respond static files without asking django process requests like "five me that static file" and gives ability to cache static files. And it speed-up all work.

So, if you serveer is setted up to take static files from static dir (looks like `DOMAIN/public/static/main/` is the static dir) it will have no idea about changes in the project dir (looks like `DOMAIN/project_book/main/static/main/` is a project dir).

But I agree with @Sause, looks like you have to be very carefull and have exact understanding of what you're doing with killing any process on the production server.

I think it could be useful for you to read Django documentation about static files too. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

Comment: I did talk to the developer. She is going to give me a script to run to restart the python script, thought it was odd that I cant just change an image and it doesn't show on the front end. She said for me not to touch the public directory only the main/static to edit then i have to run the script